# Why can't lubridate convert dates in a tbl_df?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a variable named `x` that is like this:

```
x <- structure(list(Time = c("2002-05-07 21:00", "2002-05-08 21:00", 
                             "2002-05-09 21:00", "2002-05-10 21:00", 
                             "2002-05-11 21:00", "2002-05-13 21:00", 
                             "2002-05-14 21:00", "2002-05-15 21:00",
                             "2002-05-16 21:00", "2002-05-17 21:00")), 
               .Names = "Time", class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), 
               row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Now, I'd like to convert the strings in `x` into dates and since `x[1,1] %>% lubridate::ymd_hm()` gives me the expected result for a single element, I thought the following would do the trick:

```
x %>% lubridate::ymd_hm()
```

But it does not work (result is NA) and I get the following warning:

```
    Warning message:
    All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Why doesn't `x %>% lubridate::ymd_hm()` work the way I had expected it and what can I do to get the result I want?

Comment: Your data has been truncated.

Comment: `ymd_hm(x$Time)` work stellarly. Why would you think `x %>% lubridate::ymd_hm()` would know to get the `Time` column?

Comment: Or just use the normal function that lubridate ultimately will under the hood anyway - `as.POSIXct(x$Time,tz="UTC")` or wrap your original code in mutate referencing the specific variable `x %>% mutate(Time=ymd_hm(Time))`

Comment: @thelatemail I wasn't taking your answer btw, sorry I didn't see that you had the same solution in the comments : )

Comment: If you have to use pipes `x %>% .[[1]] %>% lubridate::ymd_hm()`

Comment: @PierreLafortune - no apology needed, imaginary internet points don't count for much in the real world :-)

Comment: What? I thought the counted as S&H Green stamps. No wonder they laughed at me in the supermarket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `mutate` works.

```
x %>% mutate(Time = ymd_hm(Time))
```

Answer (score 3):

This succeeds (with a warning that I don't understand but I suspect that the rownames of that object may have something to do with it.):

```
x %>% lubridate::ymd_hm(.$Time)
 [1] NA                        "2002-05-07 21:00:00 UTC" "2002-05-08 21:00:00 UTC"
 [4] "2002-05-09 21:00:00 UTC" "2002-05-10 21:00:00 UTC" "2002-05-11 21:00:00 UTC"
 [7] "2002-05-13 21:00:00 UTC" "2002-05-14 21:00:00 UTC" "2002-05-15 21:00:00 UTC"
[10] "2002-05-16 21:00:00 UTC" "2002-05-17 21:00:00 UTC"

x[1,1] %>% lubridate::ymd_hm() 
#[1] "2002-05-07 21:00:00 UTC"
```